Input a string to a int variable inside a loop
im new to C++ and i just find out that if i ask a user input for a variable with int data type in a while loop, the loop just keep repeating without asking for another input, why can this happen?
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
   while(true){
      int x;
      cout<<"Enter x: ";
      cin>>x;
      cout<<"You enter"<<x<<endl;
   }
   return 0;
}

I tried to make menu inside a loop called menu, the menu contains options that are numbers so i declared an integer variable. I think if i enter string, it will just execute the code in the default case of the switch and continues the loop normally.

while(true) means you want to execute the loop unconditionally

Also there is no switch statement in your code. Post all code that is relevant.

"just keep repeating without asking for another input" what do you mean ? When I run your code, it keeps asking for input, printing it then ask for another input etc. (in an infinite loop due to the while(true)).

if (!(cin>>x)) throw std::runtime_error("input error"); ... because otherwise the code is not handling input failure, and that can cause things to go badly.

When x is an int, what do you expect cin >> x to do when you type dog?   Because what it DOES do is (1) encounter the d  in cins stream buffer (2) leaves the d (and subsequent characters) in cins stream buffer, unread and (3) places cin in an error state.    If cin >> x is performed again, it returns immediately due to the error state.  If you want your code to "cope" with the input dog, you need to both (1)  clear cins error state and (2) clear the characters d, o, and g from the stream.   If you don't, then (in your code) you have an infinite loop.

If you enter a string that cannot be converted to an integer then your int variable will get a value of zero, cin will stop working, and your program will continue. That's what the rules of C++ says will happen.

Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes the exact input required to reproduce the problem.

Have you studied functions yet?
They allow you to break a program into pieces, which can make it easier to understand.
The following program implements a simple menu using three functions:

get_int – Input an integer from the user. Keep looping until the entry is valid, and in range. Function get_int seems to be what you are trying to code in the OP.
main_menu – Display a menu, and execute the user's choice. Keep looping until the user chooses to quit.
main – Driver routine calls main_menu.

// main.cpp
#include <iostream>  // cin, cout, streamsize
#include <limits>    // numeric_limits
#include <string>    // string

int get_int(
    std::string const& prompt,
    int const min,
    int const max)
{
    int n{};
    for (;;)  // "infinite" loop
    {
        std::cout << prompt;
        if (!(std::cin >> n))
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid entry. Please reenter.\n\n";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        else if (n < min || n > max)
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid entry. Please reenter.\n"
                << "Entries must be between " << min << " and " << max << ".\n\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            break;  // break out of for-loop
        }
    }
    return n;
}

void main_menu() {
    char const* const menu{
        "M A I N   M E N U"
        "\n"
        "\n 1. Say hello"
        "\n 2. Say goodbye"
        "\n 3. Quit"
        "\n\n"
    };
    enum { SayHello = 1, SayGoodbye, Quit };
    for (;;) {
        std::cout << menu;
        int const choice{ get_int("Choice? ", 1, 3) };
        std::cout << '\n';
        switch (choice) {
        case SayHello:
            std::cout << "Hello, world!\n\n\n";
            break;
        case SayGoodbye:
            std::cout << "So long, y'all!\n\n\n";
            break;
        case Quit:
            return;
        default:
            break;  // unreachable
        }
    }
    // unreachable
}

int main() {
    main_menu();
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp

Explanatory notes follow.
Function get_int
This function has three parameters: prompt, min, and max. It displays the prompt, and then attempts to input variable n (an int) from the user. The value entered by the user must be a valid integer between min and max, otherwise, the function displays an error message, and loops back, asking the user to try again.
The value returned by function get_int is guaranteed to be a valid integer between min and max.

for(;;) is an infinite loop. It keeps repeating until the break-statement forces an exit.

If cin is expecting an int, and the user makes a non-numeric (text) entry, cin will be placed into a failed state. After that, all subsequent operations on cin will fail. cin.clear restores cin to a good state, so that subsequent operations do not automatically fail.

After a non-numeric entry, it is not enough just to clear cin. You must also discard the invalid entry still sitting in the input stream. That is what cin.ignore does. The version used here discards all characters up to (and including) the newline character ('\n') that marks the end of the line. See CppReference for details.

if (!(std::cin >> n)) is a test that detects non-numeric text entries. It says, in essence, "if (cin fails while inputing variable n)," but the explanation is nuanced. The subexpression std::cin >> n does two things: (1) attempt to input variable n, and (2) return a reference to std::cin to the surrounding expression. So, !(std::cin >> n) evaluates to !(std::cin). Without going into the details of the conversion operators that are defined for std::cin, this latter expression, !(std::cin), is converted to !(!std::cin.fail()). The two logical negations (!) cancel out, so you are left with std::cin.fail(), and an if-statement that can be read as "if (cin fails while inputing variable n)."


Function get_int also calls cin.ignore after a successful entry. Without it, the newline character that terminates a valid entry would be left on the input stream. In most cases, that is not a problem. If, however, a program also usesstd::getline, discarding the newline allows a subsequent call to std::getline to behave as expected. For more information, see the many posts on Stack Overflow that explain how to mix cin >> value and std::getline in the same program.
Function main_menu
This function displays a menu, and calls function get_int to input the user's choice. A switch-statement executes code for the selected option. The switch-statement is placed within an infinite loop, so that the menu keeps repeating until the user selects option 3 ("Quit").
In a menu like this, the switch statement usually calls a separate function for each menu option. Here, however, the code is simple enough that it can be coded within the switch-statement itself.
If you want to call a separate function, replace std::cout << "Hello, world!\n\n\n"; with a call to a function such as say_hello() below:
void say_hello() {
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n\n\n";
}

Similarly, the statement std::cout << "So long, y'all!\n\n\n"; can be replaced by a call to function say_goodbye().
The declaration of variable menu is not as simple as it seems. menu is a "local" variable of type char const* const. Reading from right-to-left (which is often the easiest way to read a type declaration in C++), its type is "const pointer to const char." It is initialized with the string literal that begins with "M A I N   M E N U".
When you use a string-literal in a program, its value is allocated in the static storage area as an array of const char. Its value is a "C-string" that is terminated by the null character ('\0'). At the place where a string-literal is referenced (i.e., used), the compiler substitutes a pointer to the string-literal. More precisely, the array decays into a pointer to its first character. This is the pointer used by the compiler.
Thus, the type of variable menu is char const* const. Equally well, it could be declared using type char const*. I have added the extra (trailing) const, because it is my habit to declare as const any object that is not modified after its original initialization.
If you like, you can simplify the declaration by using auto.
auto const menu{
    "M A I N   M E N U"
    "\n"
    "\n 1. Say hello"
    "\n 2. Say goodbye"
    "\n 3. Quit"
    "\n\n"
};

The enumeration enum { SayHello = 1, SayGoodbye, Quit }; is a bit of syntatic sugar that allows the case labels of the switch statement to use the self-documenting names of the enumeration constants.
case SayHello: 
    ...
case SayGoodbye:
    ...
case Quit:
    ...

Finally, in C++23, the two lines marked with the comment // unreachable can be replaced by calls to std::unreachable. In debug builds, std::unreachable() often compiles into something similar to assert(false). In release builds, it usually vanishes, while hinting to the compiler that relevant optimizations (if any) may be applied.

I can get input i.e. it asks me to enter x for every iteration. but your code does not terminate in any condition. I would suggest you to apply a do while loop with the codition to check if the user wants to run the loop again or not. If they want to run, the condition would be true, else it would be false.
Or if you want to  get inputs in the form of string you can explicitly typecast it as string(x) or use the in-built function to_string(x).

explicitly typecast it as string(x) This would be convenient, but no. You have to convert with to_string or similar. There is no path from number to string via casting.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
